# Use only one big regular expression in C

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I'm writing an engine in C with libpcre that filters (in my case, a filter accepts or refuses a string) some log lines of the form:

```
tok1=foo tok2=bar ... tok3="value with spaces in it" ...
```

So, my way to filter them is to receive from the user a filter string of the form:

```
"tok1=regex1 tok2=regex2 tok3!=regex3 ..."
```

At the beginning, my engine parses this pattern, compiles all found regexes with pcre_compile/pcre_study and store them into a hashtable (or a radix).

```
("tok1"->pcre_regex1, "tok2"->pcre_regex2, "tok3"->pcre_regex3)
```

(by the way, the "!=" operator is used to filter lines which do NOT contains the following regex.)

Then, during the filtering phase itself, for every log line, I walk the line from beginning to end, char by char, I get token/value couples and if there is a regex relative to the token in my hashtable, the value must match the regex (pcre_exec) otherwise the line is rejected.

It works fine.

My question is: I am very skeptical but I was wondering if it is possible to write a single big regular expression which combine all my regex to filter lines and taking in account possible double-quotes to do:

```
pcre_exec(my_big_re, NULL, my_whole_log_line, len, 0, 0, NULL, 0)
```

Ho, and a subsidiary question : is it possible to write a *negative* of ANY regular expression of any form? (I am skeptical too)

Comment: You could probably do it with some crazy combinations of lookaheads and wildcards.  But to be honest?  Probably not worth it.  The method you devised looks much cleaner - and likely faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Regular expressions are exactly equivalent to finite state machines, and it's trivial to negate a finite state machine (make all accepting states non-accepting, and vice-versa). However, you'll find that doing this causes an exponentially bigger regular expression in the worst case.

Comment: Ok, as my question was too vague, I'm validating your answer which is correct :)